# speed up prime number generating

Tags: swift, primes

I have written a program that generates prime numbers . It works well but I want to speed it up as it takes quite a while for generating the all the prime numbers till 10000

```
var list = [2,3]
var limitation = 10000
var flag = true
var tmp = 0

for (var count = 4 ; count <= limitation ; count += 1 ){


    while(flag && tmp <= list.count - 1){
        if (count % list[tmp] == 0){
            flag = false

        }else if ( count % list[tmp] != 0 && tmp != list.count - 1  ){
            tmp += 1
        }else if ( count % list[tmp] != 0 && tmp == list.count - 1  ){
            list.append(count)

        }
    }
flag = true
tmp = 0
}

print(list)
```

Comment: Have you tried the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_and_variants)?

Comment: Wikipedia has an [intro article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) on the different algorithms

Comment: style-wise, you should really use [`break`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID441) to end your loops at the right time. and no need to repeat the same test thrice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Nick already explained, you can also easily take advantage of the following property: **all primes greater than 3 are congruent to 1 or -1 mod 6**.

Because you've already included 2 and 3 in your initial list, you can therefore start with `count = 6`, test `count - 1` and `count + 1` and increment by 6 each time.

Below is my first attempt ever at Swift, so pardon the syntax which is probably far from optimal.

```
var list = [2,3]
var limitation = 10000
var flag = true
var tmp = 0
var max = 0

for(var count = 6 ; count <= limitation ; count += 6) {
  for(var d = -1; d <= 1; d += 2) {
    max = Int(floor(sqrt(Double(count + d))))

    for(flag = true, tmp = 0; flag && list[tmp] <= max; tmp++) {
      if((count + d) % list[tmp] == 0) {
        flag = false
      }
    }
    if(flag) {
      list.append(count + d)
    }
  }
}
print(list)
```

I've tested the above code on [iswift.org/playground](http://iswift.org/playground) with limitation = 10,000, 100,000 and 1,000,000.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity: the most significant speed up comes from the introduction of the `max` upper-bound. Testing only 6n-1 and 6n+1 is a marginal speed up which avoids computing the square root and entering the inner loop for all other cases. But we would have exited the inner loop on the 1st or 2nd iteration anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Two simple improvements that will make it fast up through 100,000 and maybe 1,000,000.

#### All primes except 2 are odd

Start the loop at 5 and increment by 2 each time.  This isn't going to speed it up a lot because you are finding the counter example on the first try, but it's still a very typical improvement.

#### Only search through the square root of the value you are testing

The square root is the point at which a you half the factor space, i.e. any factor less than the square root is paired with a factor above the square root, so you only have to check above or below it.  There are far fewer numbers below the square root, so you should check the only the values less than or equal to the square root.

Take 10,000 for example.  The square root is 100.  For this you only have to look at values less than the square root, which in terms of primes is roughly 25 values instead of over 1000 checks for all primes less than 10,000.

#### Doing it even faster

Try another method altogether, like a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  These methods are much faster but have a higher memory overhead.